# Как узнать номер последней строки в таблице?

Tags: php, mysql

Как узнать номер последней строки в таблице?

Comment: Что такое номер последней строки? Сосчитайте количество строк

      select count(*) from tab;

Comment: А если не считая их

Comment: В mysql нет строк. 

Пример, который привел товарищ @alexlz очень хорош. Воспользуйтесь им.

Answer (score 1):

Это невозможно. В таблице нет номеров строк, на которые можно полагаться.

Comment: Спсасибо решил с использованием SELECT MAX(id) FROM table

Comment: id - это не номер строки в таблице.

Comment: А что тогда

Comment: это всегда возрастающее число, которое является частью данных. Не номером строки. Представьте, что вы вставили три строки с id 1, 2 и 3. А затем строку с id = 2 удалили. Автоинкремент - не номер строки. Это просто число, определяющее строку. Есть строка в таблице - есть число, нет строки - нет числа в таблице.

Comment: А как тогда опредилить

Comment: определить что? последний id, вставленный вами? last_insert_id().

Answer (score 0):

Может вам поможет это  [mysql-insert-id](http://www.php.su/functions/?mysql-insert-id) свойство